# Netty Channel closed detection

Tags: ios, timeout, protocols, netty

I am building a server client application using netty and ios, I am facing a problem when the user just turns off WiFi on his/her ios device, the netty server does not know about it.
The server needs to know to do cleanup for that user and set him/her offline, but now when the user tries to connect again, the server just tells him that he/she is already online.

Answer (score 16):

If I understood your problem correctly: You want to listen for client channel closed events in server side and do some session cleanup,

There are two ways to listen for channel closed events in Netty :

1) If your server handler extends `SimpleChannelHandler/SimpleChannelHandler`, then you can override following method and write your session cleanup logic there

```
public void channelClosed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception;
```

2) If you have only access to the channel reference, then you can get the channel close future and register your implementation of `ChannelFutureListener` with your session cleanup logic,

```
ChannelFuture closeFuture = channel.closeFuture();

closeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        //session cleanup logic
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I have implemented the channelClosed method, and it works fine when the user closes the application for example, but if the user just losses his wifi connection, this method is not called.

Comment: then better to add a IdleStateHandler with a optimum read idle timeout. If the user is idle more than that time, most probably it could be connection lost case, so close the connection on IdleStateEvent from your server handler.

Comment: In newer versions of Netty, `getCloseFuture()` seems to be `closeFuture()`

Answer (score 3):

Use [IdleStateHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html)

You can detect when there is no request/responses in given time intervals.

Answer (score 2):

well the question is 9 years old a lot has happened since then
2008 Economic Collapse, Wars, Coronavirus.
On the bright side small Stock-Retailers seem to be winning the war against Hedge-funds on Wall-Street.

Back to the Question:
We were facing a similar problem where we had to provide a log message on the server-side every-time a client would close the channel.
The solutions provided above did not help but after 9 years a lot might have also changed in Netty.

Instead we extended our handler with the "MessagetoMessageDecoder" which also extends the ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.
We then override the void method "channelUnregistered" which triggers when a channel is unregistered from its EventLoop.

```
public void channelUnregistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.fireChannelUnregistered();
    //Your logic goes here...
}
```

This also works when the server itself closes the channel.
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Check session id and allow renegotiation. Or you may use something like cookie controller.
May I ask off topic question: How does your client on ios interact with netty server? (what framework you use on client side, and what decoder/encoder use? )