# Handle netty asynchronous writes and closes

Tags: asynchronous, netty, channel

I'm responsible for the maintenance and evolution of an already developed SMTP proxy for about a month now.

During some research about other aspects of this application I found the link below that states that channel writes are not synchronous and subsequent closes must be done using a listener.

[Netty Channel closed detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785949/netty-channel-closed-detection)

Questions:

1. Is this valid for version 3.6.3 (Final) of Netty API?
2. Considering that this is valid, is there any problem to store the `ChannelFuture` returned by a channel's "write" operation for future usage?

The reason for question "2" is:

I've made an initial analysis of the application's code and there is lots of places with writes, closes and write with subsequent close (one command right after the other).

The only way, I could realize, to handle all operations, given the asynchronous nature of this aspect of Netty, involves the storing of `ChannelFuture` returned by all writing operations so I can use them to schedule close operations.

Basically I would create a helper with methods "write" and "close" and hold a `Map<Channel, ChannelFuture>`. Always that a write is called, I put a new record on this map with the channel itself and the `ChannelFuture` returned by the channel's "write" operation.

When a "close" helper method is invoked, I firstly try to find the channel on this map. If I can't find it, there is no pending write operation, so I can close the channel right away. Otherwise, I have a pending write, so I use the stored `ChannelFuture` to register a listener scheduling the channel's closing.